# Not able to call Collections.sort(arrayList)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to sort an arraylist of objects `Employee` by the salary of the employees. I have stored all the `Employee` objects in the `ArrayList` and trying to call `Collections.sort(list)` but having the error(eclipse).
please see the screenshot[image]

What should I do.?
I am having this error while implementing Comparable<> interface, I have alredy added the **method compareTo**
[image]

Comment: `sort` is defined as `static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
void sort(List<T> list)`, which means `T` needs to extend `Comparable<? super T>` ... is `Employees` `Comparable`?

Comment: @Eran its java.util.ArrayList

Comment: class Employees implements Comparable<Employees> {...}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class `Employee` has to implement `Comparable` to use the `Collections.sort()`, and you have to define how `Employee` objects should be compared in the `compareTo(Employee e)` method.

So in your context, it should be something like that:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        //this is an example. Obviously, you can put whatever you want here 
        return (int)(this.salary-o.salary);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort objects based on an attribute value, you have to write your own **Comparator** class. For example:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

   @Override
   public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {

     if(emp1.getSalary()>emp2.getSalary())
         return  1;
     else
        return -1;
  }
}
```

then use Collections to sort the list.

```
Collections.sort(allEmployees,new MyComparator());
```